# Unable to connect to mysql running in docker container inside rhel host from windows machine

Tags: linux, networking, mysql, docker

I am developing a Java application where I want to connect my MYSQL WorkBench client to MySQL Server which is running on a Docker container on a red hat machine.

Here's my setup:

1. MySQL WorkBench ( Windows Machine -> Host A)
2. RedHat Server( Host B -> IP: 172.16.xx.xx)
3. Docker Container running MySQL on Port 3306 (IP : 172.17.0.2)

Port on RedHat 3306 has been bound to Port 3306 inside the docker container.

Now, whenever I try to connect my Windows machine tunneled to the RedHat machine for the 3306 port, it says you cannot connect to MySQL server.

Any leads will be appreciated.